What is the meaning of "administrées" in "[...] sous réserve que leurs preuves soient administrées au grand jour"?
I just read the following RFI article regarding the latest news from Africa:
Ce que j'ai du mal à comprendre, c'est la phrase suivante :

...certains activistes toute honte bue ravalent leur fiel, en tout
cas, sous réserve que leurs preuves soient administrées au grand jour
!

Administrées? How does administrées fit in this context?
